# Why does the rule not work?

Tags: java, antlr4

```
VARNAME:[_a-zA-Z0-9.]+;

prog:expression +;

expression: VARNAME |
    '!' expression |
    expression '=' expression |
    expression '+=' expression |
    expression '-=' expression |
    expression ('<'|'>') expression |
    expression  expression |
    expression ('+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'%') expression |
    expression ('=='|'!=') expression |
    expression ('>='|'<=') expression |
    expression ('&&'|'||') expression |
    expression ('++'|'--') |
    ('++'|'--') expression |    
    '(' expression ')'|
    '\'' expression '\'' |
    expression ',' expression |
    expression '*' |
    '(' expression ')' expression |
    expression '->' expression |
    expression expression |           //var decl
    expression '<' expression '>' expression |  //class template
    expression '[' expression ']' |         //array
    expression '.' expression |            //class obj
    expression '(' expression? ')' |          //func call
    '{' expression '}';
```

The parse Text :

```
    (CKbdpBase*)handle->open();
```

The rule doesn't work, it notices `"(CKbdpBase*)"` can't be parsed correctly.

How do I fix the rule?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. You didn't even post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed:

- `VARNAME` inside `expression`
- A semicolon at the end of `prog` rule: `prog: expression + ';' ;`